Black and white (maybe), movie/ tv episode - alien assassins
There's a movie - or possibly a 'Twilight Zone' type TV episode - I've been trying to find for a long time. Here's what I I remember:

I remember it as black and white.
The basic premise involved a humanoid alien (possibly human, but I remember him as alien) on the run from a team of humanoid alien assassins.
While trying to escape them, he meets an attractive female human that he becomes attracted to.
She doesn't believe him at first, but eventually does, and they run together from the assassination team.
One by one they're able to take out the assassins until there's only one left.
They end up in an empty old ghost town with the last of the assassins close behind. They're almost taken out, but the hunted alien manages to kill the last pursuing assassin. All is well - cue happy ending...
... or not :-). Because the woman was really one of the hunters all along. She shoots the man she's been 'running' with. Roll credits.


Are you looking for this (The Love War from 1970)? [Also, please add the 'identify-this-movie' tag to ID questions]

I think I may be! My thanks indeed - I'll go try to find it, and if I can get it let you know the result :-). Oh - and I tried to add the tag you mentioned - but it doesn't seem to exist. There's one for TV Episode and one for actor, but not one for movie :-(.

Adding a bit to Walt's comment...
Yes, pretty sure you're thinking about "The Love War" - I still have it on VHS somewhere...  I especially remember Lloyd Bridges (from a couple of other movies I'd seen at the time also).  
It's about two alien races who's deciding which of them gets to dominate this part of the galaxy and/or Earth.  They agree to each send a two(?)-man team to hunt each other - the last man standing takes it all.
They are disguised as humans, but each have glasses which can see through the disguise.  They also have ray-guns - I think it pretty much vaporizes them without a trace (not quite sure). 
After his partner is killed, Bridges character meets a woman (I think she saw a kill) - and I think he falls for her.  He explains who he is and why he's there - he's one of the "good guys", as the other race are into all sorts of bad things (genocide, slavery, destruction).  She follows him, as he hunts down the other team.
After he's killed the last one in a ghost town, he turns and find her pointing a ray-gun at him.  She explains that the other race found this to important to leave to chance, so they sent a third player - her (or he comes to that conclusion himself).  He looks through the glasses, and sees her as she really is.  She then shoots him.
As she walks away, the camera lowers, and we see through the lost glasses on the ground how she really look - more or less like a humanoid "blob".
So, does this still sound familiar?
